# Suggestions regarding switching Career from Low Code Developer profile to Application Developer

Tags: career-switch

I have overall 7 years of experience in IT.

Initially as a Fresher I was trained in Java , J2EE skills but when I got into actual project it was all C# and XSLT based programming...

Since I wanted to learn something new and was very fond of Coding. I just learnt C# and all programming concepts of Multi threading , Design patterns SQL etc .

I was not actually coding the complex stuffs since I was junior that time but I learnt a lot from the senior developers there.
Eventually I also learnt AWS and creating SAas solutions in AWS .
I found it very interesting...

But then I had to leave the company and I got offer in a Product company hiring me as a Full stack developer but then I was told I will be working on creating Workflow based solutions using their Low code tools...
I thought it will be a good experience so accepted the offer...

Now it has been 2 years since I am in this company and I am now creating Workflow and solutions using their Low code tools which I don't find much intersting..
Now the actual problem is that I was liking my previous job profile where I was into AWS and CI CD pipeline migration along with creating Rest Application, in my current profile there is learning all these using low code tools which is not at all interesting...

For any such requirements have to contact the Product team to incorporate those changes but in previous company even though being a service company we used to help in actual coding of the product also...

Being in current role also requires too much learning of using the Tools for doing a Business requirements and if I want to brush my previous technical skills that will also require too much effort now..
So I want to know how should I focus in such way... Should I focus on my passion or should I just work on my current job profile which is not of much interest to me using low code tools...

If I have to switch job also I would like to go into proper AWS and application developer instead of using low code tools... How to show my current experience to fit into the technical skills that I learn ?

If I enroll in some course or do certifications also in AWS or that area will it be enough to show in my profile ??

How can I improve my skills in my interested technology and change my Resume showing my current Work fitting to the technology I learn ??

Comment: Breaking this up into paragraphs and cutting out all the field-specific detail would help.

Comment: Career advice is off-topic here so will be closed, but as a more general point please format your posts so they are not one great wall of text.

Comment: Why is it not career advice ?? The question which I am asking is that I was skilled in Java and aws but due to personal reasons had to switch job and here I am into all Low code tools and workflows which I am not much interested in. So my question  is I am in this new job for past 2 years now and even if I want to try for a new job which involves more of Coding then how shud I proceed with that.

Comment: This question should be edited to remove most of its contents. Only the last two sentences are relevant. Your background doesn't matter. You just need to say that it doesn't match what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

My advice is to do your current job, get your work done and deliver basic results. Don't work overtime, don't put additional energy into the current job. Then, at night and on weekends, invest in looking for your next job where you can actually code.

If you can already code, then you may not need to learn any additional skills. Before you invest time and money on learning new skills, it would be a good idea to apply for some software developer roles (maybe shoot for mid-level of seniority) and get feedback to know where you stand. Roles where you have take-home exercises can be good in this way, because you can demonstrate your current skill level.

Not all job processes include feedback, so in that scenario, it might be a good idea to send the code that you've written in the past, or for a take home exercise and send it to a hiring manager or more senior engineer (Engineering Manager or similar) and ask for feedback. Preferably someone you respect in your network, if not, reach out cold on LinkedIn.

Through this, you should be able to get enough feedback to know where your skill level is at, and where you may need to improve to land the role that you want.

Comment: thank u for your answer. Are there any Websites or portals where I can spend sometime in building use cases using my coding skills and as u said ask for evaluation in my contacts.